# Promise pending while calling a function from contract using web3

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment

I have deployed a contract for producing hash :

```
Contract Hash
{   
  function sethash(string id)public pure returns(bytes32)
  {  
    return(keccak256(id));
  }
}
```

Now I am calling this function using web3js

```
    var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3('https://rinkeby.infura.io/infura_key')
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(HashABI, 'HashAddress')
var number
number = contract.methods.sethash("123456789").call()
console.log(number)
```

But instead of giving me hash it is showing :

```
     Promise { <pending> }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call()` is an asyncronous method. It has to wait until your node responds with the information which potentially take a lot of time, and therefore returns a promise so that JavaScript can keep on doing other things. To get the returned value out the promise, try the following code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3('https://rinkeby.infura.io/infura_key')
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(HashABI, 'HashAddress')

// Here, we pass a function to the promise using 'then()'
// to tell it how to act when it receives the information from your node
contract.methods.sethash("123456789").call().then(function(number) {  
    console.log(number)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
number = contract.methods.sethash("123456789").call()
```

To this:

```
number = await contract.methods.sethash("123456789").call()
```

Comment: You might want to add that the `await` keyword is only valid in `async` functions

Comment: @Henk: True, but this dude specified his code in global scope, not inside a function.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your code won't run in global scope

Comment: @Henk: Yes, but you're wrong in the fact that it's not my code. When this dude adds `await`, he will get `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`, which he can then fix easily. I couldn't find a way to specify `async` in my answer, because the code at question did not include any function to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use async before and 
//use await here
var contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(HashABI, 'HashAddress')
```